# SQL Trouble finding SUM Costs of Object grouped by the object on different dates

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I'm having issues putting together a query that will take data like this:

```
DATE        OBJ    COST
20180101      A       5
20180101      B       2
20180101      A       3
20180102      B       4
20180102      B       4
20180102      A       2
```

And output data that looks like this:

```
DATE        OBJ    COST
20180101      A       8
20180101      B       2
20180102      A       2
20180102      B       8
```

I have a feeling this will involve sub-queries and I've tried to understand them and use them effectively, but I cannot seem to grasp this concept easily.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: will you show us what you tried so far? this is extreme basics so curious what did not work for you here

Comment: Hi Mikhail, sorry I forgot to include my query:

`SELECT DATE, SUM(Cost), OBJ 
From tableOne 
GROUP BY OBJ`.  My issue was I wasn't using a double group by, which I didn't realize was possibly so that was an issue on my part, thank you for looking at this for me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need `group by`:

```
select date, obj, sum(cost) as cost
from t
group by date, obj
order by date, obj;
```

This is pretty basic SQL.  If you don't understand the basics, you should consider a tutorial of some sort.

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  Yeah I was using a group by, I should have mentioned that and posted a sample of my code, my apologies.

I was using the group by, but I guess I had a lapse of thought and couldn't grasp the double group by working, I've gone through basic courses on Udemy, but didn't ever use a double group by so that was where I wasn't fully grasping this.  Using this help out a ton, and I'll remember it going forward.  Thank you so much!